# New UserControl not showing up

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I have `UserControl` called "LinqView" where I have menu with buttons.

After user click button I want to display new `UserControl` using MVVM.

I have created new model class called "UsersModel" and new `UserControl` called "ViewUsersUserControl".

But I don't know why is not working.

Below is my xaml & cs code.

**LinqView.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="LayoutMVVM.Views.LinqView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LayoutMVVM.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"

             xmlns:veiwmodels="clr-namespace:LayoutMVVM.ViewModels.MojeDBModel"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:LayoutMVVM.Views.MojeDBViews" >             

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="UsersTemp" DataType="{x:Type veiwmodels:UsersModel}">
            <views:ViewUsersUserControl DataContext="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid Background="LemonChiffon">

        <Menu Height="32" Name="Menu" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="_Menu">
                <MenuItem Header="Add User" Click="MenuItem_VU" />
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**LinqView.cs**

```
private void MenuItem_VU(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataContext = new UsersModel();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried like this?

```
 <UserControl x:Class="LayoutMVVM.Views.LinqView"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LayoutMVVM.Views"
                 mc:Ignorable="d" 
                 d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"

                 xmlns:veiwmodels="clr-namespace:LayoutMVVM.ViewModels.MojeDBModel"
                 xmlns:views="clr-namespace:LayoutMVVM.Views.MojeDBViews" >             

        <UserControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type veiwmodels:UsersModel}">
                <views:ViewUsersUserControl DataContext="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </UserControl.Resources>

        <Grid Background="LemonChiffon">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Menu " Height="32" Name="Menu" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <MenuItem Header="_Menu">
                    <MenuItem Header="Add User" Click="MenuItem_VU" />
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
           <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding UsersModel}"/>
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

and your C# class should look like,

```
public class MainViewModel
{
 public UsersModel UsersModel {get;set;}
 // other properties
}
```

and in menu click,

```
   private void MenuItem_VU(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
```

i have removed key on DataTemplate.

**Update:**
Simple working sample,

MainWindow.cs

```
namespace WpfApplication29
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
        }
    }

    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public LinqViewModel LinqModel
        {
            get; set;
        } = new LinqViewModel();

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            SelectedMainModel = LinqModel;
        }
        private object selectedModel;
        public object SelectedMainModel
        {
            get
            {
                return selectedModel;
            }
            set
            {
                selectedModel = value;
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void Notify(string name)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    public class LinqViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public UserModel UserModel
        {
            get; set;
        } = new UserModel();

        private object selectedChildModel;
        public object SelectedChildModel
        {
            get
            {
                return selectedChildModel;
            }
            set
            {
                selectedChildModel = value;
                Notify("SelectedChildModel");
            }

        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void Notify(string name)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    public class UserModel
    {

    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApplication29.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication29"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="525"
    Height="350"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:LinqViewModel}">
            <local:LinqView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:UserModel}">
            <local:UserView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedMainModel}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

User UserControl

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="WpfApplication29.UserView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication29"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="300"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid >
        <TextBlock Text="From UserView"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

LinqView Usercontrol xaml

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="WpfApplication29.LinqView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication29"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="300"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid Background="LemonChiffon">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Menu  Height="32" Name="Menu" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="_Menu">
                <MenuItem Header="Add User" Click="MenuItem_VU" />
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding SelectedChildModel}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Linqview usercontrol cs

```
namespace WpfApplication29
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for LinqView.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class LinqView : UserControl
    {
        public LinqView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MenuItem_VU(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            (this.DataContext as LinqViewModel).SelectedChildModel = (this.DataContext as LinqViewModel).UserModel;
        }
    }
}
```

this sample follows multilevel hierarchy. hope this helps.

Comment: I got error:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll

Additional information: Layout recursion reached allowed limit to avoid stack overflow: '2047'. Either the tree contains a loop or is too deep.

Comment: please see the updated code, since both shared same DataContext, issue happened. you can try like updated.

Comment: it's possible that you can upload example of the project? as I still got the same error......because Into MenuItem_VU I'm creating new UsersModel () not MainViewModel

Comment: You need to create new model for inside control,, if you use the same for both control it wont work.just create a class,which have usersmodel as a property.. if that didnt work, please let me know

Comment: to open first UserControl (LinqView.xaml) I'm using model called LinqViewModel. I have second model UsersModel.cs and second UserControl ViewUsersUserControl.xaml........so, in LinqView.cs I put your code to button (DataContext = new UsersModel()) ......where put get and set?

Comment: ok,, LinqView is the shown user control and you will open another usercontrol "inside" Linqview.. Is that right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138936/discussion-between-wpfuser-and-4est).

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one `UsersModel` you dont need to have it as resource template:

```
<UserControl x:Class="LayoutMVVM.Views.LinqView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LayoutMVVM.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             xmlns:veiwmodels="clr-namespace:LayoutMVVM.ViewModels.MojeDBModel"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:LayoutMVVM.Views.MojeDBViews" >             
    <DockPanel Background="LemonChiffon">
        <Menu Height="32" Name="Menu" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="_Menu">
                <MenuItem Header="Add User" />
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <views:ViewUsersUserControl />
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: views:ViewUsersUserControl should open after you click button.....now I think is on my LinqView.xaml (when I run your code)

Comment: Your naming convention is confusing... So, you have `UsersModel` which contains collection of `UsersUserModel`? (if so, you have wrong DataType on your DataTemplate + i dont see any `ItemsControl`)

Comment: In MainWindow I run one model called LinqViewModel, which open UserControl named "LinqView". Now into this I have my menu with button (code above) where I want to open new UserControl called "ViewUsersUserControl"

Comment: Try [WPFUsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42996958/new-usercontrol-not-showing-up/42997541#42997541) answer, i think (s)he nailed it.